# How to add two collections with single aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDb and would appreciate some help with this query. I wrote the following aggregation pipeline. I wrote the query from collection1 I got the output ("Conventional Energy" : 0.0036) and I wrote the query collection2 I got the output (LastMonthConsumption" : 2.08) but how to add two collection with single aggregation with(LastMonthConsumption" : 2.08 * Conventional Energy" : 0.0036/Conventional Energy" : 0.0036) this is my required output

I have this data in mongodb:

```
COLLECTION 1:DATA
{
    "slcId" : "51",
    "clientId" : "1",
    "dcuId" : "1",
    "type" : "L",
    "officeId" : "200-24",
    "lampStatus" : "OFF",
    "cummulativeKWH" : 133.7,
    "powerFactor" : 1.0,
    "createDate" : ISODate("2018-09-06T00:01:34.816Z")
},
{
    "slcId" : "52",
    "clientId" : "1",
    "dcuId" : "1",
    "type" : "L",
    "officeId" : "200-24",
    "lampStatus" : "OFF",
    "cummulativeKWH" : 133.7,
    "powerFactor" : 1.0,
    "createDate" : ISODate("2018-09-07T21:01:34.816Z")
}
COLLECTION2:DATA
{
    "_class" : "MongoStreetLightMonthlyVo",
    "timeId" : ISODate("2018-08-04T16:40:08.817Z"),
    "vendor" : "CIMCON",
    "slcId" : "123450",
    "mongoStreetLightChildVo" : {
        "totalConsumptionMtd" : 2.08,
        "prevConsumptionMtd" : 3.45,
        "perChargeKWH" : 9.85,

    }
},
{
    "_class" : "MongoStreetLightMonthlyVo",
    "timeId" : ISODate("2018-09-04T16:40:08.817Z"),
    "vendor" : "CIMCON",
    "slcId" : "123450",
    "mongoStreetLightChildVo" : {
        "totalConsumptionMtd" : 2.08,
        "prevConsumptionMtd" : 3.45,
        "perChargeKWH" : 9.85,

    }
}
```

Collection1:

```
db.collection1.aggregate([

               { $match:{"type" : "L"}},
                {
                 $count: "TOTAL_Lights"
                },
                { "$project": { 
                  "Conventional Energy": {
                 "$divide": [ 
               { "$multiply": [
               { "$multiply": [ "$TOTAL_Lights" ,0.12 ] },

                 ]},
              1000
              ]
            } 
         }},

       ])
```

output: {"Conventional Energy" : 0.0036}

Collection2:

```
    db.collection2.aggregate(
    [
    // Stage 1
    {
        $group: {
         _id:{year:{$year:"$timeId"},month:{$month:"$timeId"} },
         LastMonthConsumption  : {$sum:"$mongoStreetLightChildVo.totalConsumptionMtd"}, 

        }
    },
    {
        $redact: {
          $cond: {  if: { $and:[
            {$eq: [ "$_id.year", {$year:new Date()} ]}, 
            {$eq: [-1, {$subtract:[ "$_id.month", {$month:new Date()} ]}]}
            ]},
                  then: "$$KEEP",
                  else: "$$PRUNE"
          }
        }
    },
    {$project:{
        _id:0,
        LastMonthConsumption :1

    }
}

]
);
```

output:{
    "LastMonthConsumption" : 2.08
}

Expected output:

```
LastMonthConsumption - Conventional Energy/Conventional Energy*100
```

Comment: Hum, LastMonthConsumption * Conventional Energy/Conventional Energy = LastMonthConsumption *1 = LastMonthConsumption

Comment: sorry  matthPen my required output: LastMonthConsumption-Conventional Energy/Conventional Energy*100 this is required output please suggesat me  @ matthPen

Comment: value is negive or possitive not matter please suggest me @ matthPen

Comment: could you provide samples of your both collections?

Comment: ya i will updated sample data please find and plese solved my problem @  matthPen

Comment: thx. is "slcId" a common field, which can be used to represent relation between your two collections?

Comment: "slcId" is a common field @ matthPen

Comment: please any suggest me @  matthPen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection2.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "year": { "$year": "$timeId" }, "month": { "$month": "$timeId" }},
    "LastMonthConsumption": { "$sum": "$mongoStreetLightChildVo.totalConsumptionMtd" }
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$eq": ["$_id.year", { "$year": new Date() }] },
          { "$eq": [-1, { "$subtract": ["$_id.month", { "$month": new Date() }] }]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "collection1",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "type": "L" } },
      { "$count": "TOTAL_Lights" },
      { "$project": {
        "ConventionalEnergy": {
          "$divide": [{ "$multiply": [{ "$multiply": ["$TOTAL_Lights", 0.12] }] }, 1000]
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "ConventionalEnergy"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "totalConsumption": {
      "$multiply": [
        {
          "$divide": [
            {
              "$subtract": [
                "$LastMonthConsumption",
                { "$arrayElemAt": ["$ConventionalEnergy.ConventionalEnergy", 0] }
              ]
            },
            { "$arrayElemAt": ["$ConventionalEnergy.ConventionalEnergy", 0] }         
          ]
        },
        100
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: i will try this code some error throw Assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "arguments to $lookup must be strings, pipeline: [ { $match: { type: \"L\" } }, { $count: \"TOTAL_Lights\" }, { $project: { ConventionalEnergy: { $divide: [ { $multiply: [ { $multiply: [ \"$TOTAL_Lights\", 0.12 ] } ] }, 1000.0 ] } } } ] is type array",
 "code" : 4570, @ Anthony Winzlet

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: 3.4.4 @  Anthony Winzlet

Comment: 3.6 not updated my system if any possible 3.4? @ Anthony Winzlet

Comment: Thank you so much ...Thank you for supporting @  Anthony Winzlet

Comment: You have to update mongodb to 3.6 or above to achieve this in a single query else you cannot

Comment: Anthony Winzlet i am updated 3.6 version this code working well thank you for supporting thank you so much   Greatly appreciate the help@ Anthony Winzlet

Comment: hi  Anthony Winzlet  LAST "$project": SOME ISSUE LastMonthConsumption(0.00208)-ConventionalEnergy" :( 0.00372)/ConventionalEnergy" :( 0.00372)*100 CORRECT OUT PUT:-44.0860215  BUT TO DIPLAY OUTPUT: -0.0044086021 PLEASE CHECK @  Anthony Winzlet